# Editing a gridview by a personal Keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I did a gridview with a datatable as a datasource. I did also a form for a keyboard that write on a textbox.

I call the keyboard in this way:

```
frmKeyboard k = new frmKeyboard(myTextBox);
```

When the keys on the keyboard are pressed, the character are insert on the textbox. But for the gridview it is different. I can't pass a textbox, but i know the gridview is in "textedit" as editing.

I call the form in this way:

```
private void gridSelfLearning_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView self = sender as GridView;
    TextBox prova = null;
    if(self.ActiveEditor is TextEdit)
    {
        frmKeyboard k = new frmKeyboard(prova);
        k.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: DataGrid is an editable GridView (table view). It's more convenient to handle.

Comment: I know, but my boss want all the program do with devexpress tool

Comment: https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/6084/controls-and-libraries/data-grid

Comment: Ok, but then why don't you just pass the TextEdit control to your keyboard?

Comment: Because I'm stupid. I resolve that passing the Textedit, you were right. I modify my method of the Keyboard for work with both textedit and textbox, so now it works very well. Thank you.